# SwiftUI NavigationLink not displaying view until physical rotation then all is ok?

Tags: swiftui-navigationlink

The opening view of App is blank with a Back Button. However, the intended view will appear after complete rotation of physical device (before touching anything) or by tapping the Back Button on the displayed empty view.

This is a weird bug. After that rotation (to landscape and back to protrait) everything is peachy-keen-o.

I am aware that adding: .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) to the NavigationView will sorta resolve the problem. But this solution is a poor fix for my App's needs.

Is there a command to intentionally rotate device in code to resolve this? Or some other fix to get that first view to appear without counting on the user to rotate the device?
I've tried various solutions with no luck.

Below is a quick setup of the problem.

```
struct FirstView: View {
        @Binding var viewNum: Int?
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("View One")
                    .padding(20)
                Button {
                    viewNum = 2
                } label: {
                    Text("Go to 2nd view")
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                viewNum = 1
            }
        }
    }

    struct MainView: View {
        @State var selection: Int? = 1
        var body: some View {
           // VStack {
                NavigationView {
                    List {
                        NavigationLink("First View", tag: 1, selection: $selection){  FirstView(viewNum: $selection)}
                       
                        NavigationLink("Second View", tag: 2, selection: $selection){
                            Text("View 2").padding(20)
                            Button {
                                selection = 1
                            } label: {
                                Text("Go to first view")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
               // .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            //}
        }
    }
```

Comment: The NavigationView should be at the top. Remove the VStack

Comment: I was sooo hoping that was going to work .... But alas it was not to happen... It still shows a blank screen until I physically rotate device.